# session synchronization between socket.io server and http server?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io, multiserver

Recently I worked on a project, which is a real time web application.

I use [socket.io](http://socket.io) as the data server, and let's suppose that its domain is `www.a.com`. On the other hand, I use [express](http://expressjs.com) as the http server, and its domain is `www.b.com`.

Now the problem comes, if I want to synchronize the session between two server(that means, if user login `www.a.com` by socket.io, he/she is logged in when he/she visits `www.b.com`), how can I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

ps: please forgive my poor English...

== Update ==

I have tried one solution: use the magic of `postMessage` to communicate between different tabs.

When a user login in `www.a.com`, I create a `iframe`, whose `src` refers to `www.b.com`. And then I can pass login data from `www.a.com` to `www.b.com`, and trigger something to login in `www.b.com`.

But I think it is not a best way to solve the problem, is it safe? or generate other problem? And I wonder if there are other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

By their nature, cookies (which store session id) can't be read from different domains.  I know of a mod for Apache that could encrypt login data from one domain and place it in a GET request (address bar) so the user wouldn't then have to log into a second domain.  Sorry, I can't recall what it was called, but you could do something similar, all you'd need is require('crypto') I believe.

EDIT:  Why do you want the sockets & web server to run on different domains?  If they ran on the same domain, I believe there is a module to allow sockets.io to get the session data.  I didn't use it myself, just read about it.

Comment: I do not use cookie in socket.io, I pass a `sid`(which saves in `localStorage`) to restore user's data. So I don't know If `crypto` can help me in this scenario. I have different domains because they have different business..